# Merge 2 Yii applications

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 Yii applications on one server APP1 and APP2, APP2 get the data from APP1 Using API (cURL), but the performance is too slow because of the API, is there away to enhance this performance??
I can copy APP2 to be inside APP1 but how can I use 2 Yii apps at the same time?

Comment: Are you using 2 separate database for two different app?

Comment: no, I  use the same database but in APP2 I use 2 databases not just the shared one

Comment: You can generate module called API and copy your all API code into API module controller.

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Try to follow this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Comment: The system implemented on Yii v1